# two nested for-each loops in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<main>
  <item>
    <feed_id>44514</feed_id>
    <date_added>2/15/2014 7:01 PM</date_added>
    <type_id>20</type_id>
    <title>created a new league</title>                     
    <sender>Jordan Bahr</sender>                        
    <recipient>Jordan Bahr</recipient>                                                                                                                      
    <item_content>
      <![CDATA[bob]]>
    </item_content>                     
    <sender_thumbnail>http://ssl.playerspace.com/assets/images/placeholder.gif</sender_thumbnail>
    <sender_profile_url>http://YMCA27McArthur279853.localsportswire.org</sender_profile_url>                                                        
    <item_content_url/>
    <program_created>
      <league_id>1228</league_id>
      <league_name>McArthur Family YMCA Spring Soccer</league_name>
      <league_url>http://mcarthursoccer.localsportswire.org</league_url>
      <league_logo>http://content.localsportswire.org/images/default_logos/yorangegreen.png</league_logo>
      <league_city>Amelia Island</league_city>
      <league_state>FL</league_state>
      <league_definition>league</league_definition>
      <sport>soccer</sport>
    </program_created>
  </item>

  <item>
    <feed_id>44492</feed_id>
    <date_added>2/13/2014 4:05 PM</date_added>
    <type_id>20</type_id>
    <title>created a new league</title>                     
    <sender>Jordan Bahr</sender>                        
    <recipient>Jordan Bahr</recipient>                                                                                                                      
    <item_content>
      <![CDATA[bob]]>
    </item_content>                     
    <sender_thumbnail>http://ssl.playerspace.com/assets/images/placeholder.gif</sender_thumbnail>
    <sender_profile_url>http://YMCA27McArthur279853.localsportswire.org</sender_profile_url>                                                        
    <item_content_url/>
    <program_created>   
      <league_id>1214</league_id>
      <league_name>McArthur Family YMCA Spring Volleyball</league_name>
      <league_url>http://MCAvball.localsportswire.org</league_url>
      <league_logo>http://master.localsportswire.org/assets/images/subtype1/playerspace/Team Sports/Volleyball.jpg</league_logo>                                                                                                            
      <league_city>Amelia Island</league_city>                                                                                                          
      <league_state>FL</league_state>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      <league_definition>league</league_definition>
      <sport>volleyball</sport>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    </program_created>

  </item>

</main>
```

Here is my xslt stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <ul id="feedul">

          <xsl:for-each select="main/item">
            <li class="item clearfix">
              <div class="image">
                <a>
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sender_profile_url"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>      
                  <img>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                      <xsl:value-of select="sender_thumbnail"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>    
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">img-polaroid img-rounded img-polaroid-table</xsl:attribute>                             
                  </img>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                <a>
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sender_profile_url"/>                                                 
                  </xsl:attribute>      
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">name text-info</xsl:attribute>                                                            
                  <xsl:value-of select="sender"/>
                </a> 
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ ]]></xsl:text>
                <a>
                  <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="item_content_url"/>                                                   
                  </xsl:attribute>                                      
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">name</xsl:attribute>                                      
                  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </a>
                <br/>
                <p>
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">title</xsl:attribute>                                     
                  <span>

                    <xsl:attribute name="data-id">
                      <xsl:value-of select="feed_id"/>                                                  
                    </xsl:attribute>    
                    <xsl:attribute name="data-type-id">
                      <xsl:value-of select="type_id"/>                                                  
                    </xsl:attribute>                                                                                                                                                                    
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">                                                        
                      <xsl:if test="type_id=1 or type_id=3 or type_id=21
                        or type_id=2 or  type_id=15">icon-camera</xsl:if>                                                                                                                                                                                               
                      <xsl:if test="type_id=22"
                             >icon-comment</xsl:if>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

                      <xsl:if     test="type_id=20">icon-bullhorn</xsl:if>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                    </xsl:attribute>                                                                            
                  </span>
                  Posted on <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ ]]></xsl:text>
                  <xsl:value-of select="date_added"/>
                </p>                                    
                <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->  

                <xsl:for-each select="main/item/program_created">
                  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                  <xsl:call-template name="programs">
                    <xsl:with-param name="league_logo" select = "league_logo" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="league_url" select = "league_url" />                                          
                    <xsl:with-param name="league_name" select = "league_name" />                                                
                    <xsl:with-param name="league_city" select = "league_city"     />                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    <xsl:with-param name="league_state" select = "league_state"     />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                    <xsl:with-param name="sport" select = "sport"     />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    <xsl:with-param name="league_definition" select = "league_definition"     />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                  </xsl:call-template>                                                                          
                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:call-template name="wire_post">
                  <xsl:with-param name="item_content" select = "item_content" />
                </xsl:call-template>                                                                    
                <br/>
              </div>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name = "programs" >
    <xsl:param name = "league_logo" />  
    <xsl:param name = "league_url" />   
    <xsl:param name = "league_name" />  
    <xsl:param name = "league_city" />  
    <xsl:param name = "league_state" /> 
    <xsl:param name = "sport" />        
    <xsl:param name = "league_definition" />                                                                                                    
    <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">well well-small clearfix</xsl:attribute>                                      
      <a>
        <img>
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="@league_logo"/>
          </xsl:attribute>    
          <xsl:attribute name="class">pull-left img-polaroid img-polaroid-table marginright10px</xsl:attribute>                         
        </img>          
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:value-of select="@league_url"/>                                                  
        </xsl:attribute>        
        <xsl:attribute name="class">name</xsl:attribute>                                                                
        <xsl:value-of select="@league_name"/>
      </a>              
      <div></div>
      <xsl:value-of select="@league_city"/>,
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ ]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@league_state"/>            
      <div></div>               
      A <xsl:value-of select="@sport"/> 
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ ]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@league_definition"/>               
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name = "wire_post" >
    <xsl:param name = "item_content" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$item_content" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>                                        
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does not seem to be calling the programs template on the inner for-each.

I've tried

- main/item/program_created
- item/program_created
- //program_created

Nothing seems to work.

The call to template wire_post does work. I'm at a loss for what's causing this.

Comment: How about just 'select="program_created"'?

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside a for-each loop such as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="main/item">
```

you switch your context node to the selected item (which is main/item), therefore if you write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="main/item/program_created">
```

in your inner for-each loop you are basically trying to select main/item/main/item/program_created. Instead you should use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="program_created">
```

So your inner for-each loop will select the correct node, and the body of that loop activates.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but some suggestions that might avoid other problems. I'd normally comment, but this is a bit big for that.

Your `programs` template is only working 'by accident'- you're not using any of the named parameters, parameters are used with `$param`, not `@param`. But because the context node is passed in, and the attributes on that element have the same name as the parameters, it looks like it's working.

You don't actually need to pass parameters at all for this code- if you replace `<xsl:template name="programs">` with `<xsl:template match="program_created">`, and remove ALL the parameters, you can replace the `<xsl:for-each ..>` that calls it with `<xsl:apply-templates select=program_created/>` instead, and you won't need to pass any parameters either. The only other thing you would need to do is move your `<br/>`'s into that template.

Similarly, you can call your `wire_post` template by changing it to `match="item_content"` and use `<xsl:apply-templates select="item_content"/>` instead of `<xsl:call-template ..>`, and remove all the parameter passing.

Finally, I'd recommend putting everything inside the `<xsl:for-each select="items/item">..</xsl:for-each>` in a separate template, with `<xsl:template match="item">`, and then replace your for-each with `<xsl:apply-templates select="items/item"/>`. Your context node becomes a lot clearer if it never changes within a template.